# Find Duplicates and increment value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a plsql package which needs to highlight any duplicates in the unique id field and add v2, v3 as duplicates occurs. Eg unique id 111 occurs three times - 111, 111v2 111v3.

My code highlights duplicates but treats each set as the same eg 111 v2 111 v2 111 v2

```
  PROCEDURE find_duplicates IS
      c_amt           INT;
      c_id            VARCHAR2(255);
      c_id_new        VARCHAR2(255);
      v_count         int;

      cursor c_duplicates is
        select UNIQUE_ID,Qty from (
          select UNIQUE_ID, count(*) as Qty from dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File
          group by UNIQUE_ID
          having count(*) > 1) where Qty >1;
    BEGIN
       BEGIN
          v_count := 0;

          open c_duplicates;
          LOOP
            FETCH c_duplicates into c_id, c_amt;
            v_count := v_count + 1;
            c_id_new := c_id||'_V'||v_count;

            --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('C_ID: '||c_id);
            UPDATE dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File
            SET UNIQUE_ID=c_id_new
            where unique_id=c_id;

            EXIT WHEN c_duplicates%NOTFOUND;
          END LOOP;
      END;
  END;
```

Comment: It isn't treating them all the same; it's updating all three rows three times. Look at the filter on your update - each time round the loop *all* rows matching the ID are updated. Actually, no, it will only go round the loop once for each ID - they should all end up as 111_v1? Anyway... are you sure the modified ID also won't already exist?

Comment: Thanks Alex, is this doable in SQL do you know? I am very inexperienced with PLSQL. Yes the modified ID won't exist so I simply need to just add on an incrementing v2, v3 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is only seeing each `unqiue_id` once, since you're grouping by that column; and for each ID that has multiple rows, your update is then updating all of them to the same V number. And because you aren't resetting `v_count` for each ID, the first ID that has duplicates will have all its rows updated to V1; the second ID with duplicates will have them all set to V2; etc.

You could do this with a merge; the target is a query that gets the ID and rowid of each row, and the source gets those plus the count of each ID and an arbitrary ranking of each occurrence of each one (via analytic functions):

```
create table Temp_Weekly_Export_File (unique_id varchar2(10));
insert into Temp_Weekly_Export_File values ('111');
insert into Temp_Weekly_Export_File values ('111');
insert into Temp_Weekly_Export_File values ('111');
insert into Temp_Weekly_Export_File values ('112');
insert into Temp_Weekly_Export_File values ('112');
insert into Temp_Weekly_Export_File values ('113');

merge into
(
  select unique_id, rowid
  from Temp_Weekly_Export_File
) t
using (
  select unique_id,
    row_number() over (partition by unique_id order by 1) as rnk,
    count(*) over (partition by unique_id) as cnt
  from Temp_Weekly_Export_File
) s
on (s.rowid = t.rowid and s.cnt > 1)
when matched then
update set t.unique_id = s.unique_id ||'_V'||s.rnk;

3 rows merged.

select * from Temp_Weekly_Export_File;

UNIQUE_ID 
----------
111_V1
111_V2
111_V3
112V_1
112V_2
113
```

The `on` clause has to use a column that won't be updated by the merge itself, so it can't just use `unique_id`; rowid should be stable enough here.

If you have another column that can/should determine which row is V1, which V2 etc - maybe a timestamp? - you can order by that instead of the dummy constant I used, which will assign the incremented V value indeterminately.

You may also need to prefix the table name with `dbo.`, as you are in the question. And if you need to do this in a procedure, just wrap it as MTO said:

```
PROCEDURE find_duplicates IS
BEGIN
  merge into
  (
    select unique_id, rowid
    from dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File
  ) t
  using (
    select unique_id,
      row_number() over (partition by unique_id order by 1) as rnk,
      count(*) over (partition by unique_id) as cnt
    from dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File
  ) s
  on (s.rowid = t.rowid and s.cnt > 1)
  when matched then
  update set t.unique_id = s.unique_id ||'_V'||s.rnk;
END find_duplicates;
```

Comment: Thanks, for the merge I am getting an error stating invalid table name. I have never used merge before so do I simply run that section or must I do something else?

Comment: You just run that section (you can wrap it in a procedure if you want, but it isn't necessary). Ah... I created a local table, you might need to prefix yours with `dbo.` if you aren't executing this as that user, in both the `from` clauses?

Comment: If its necessary to place the code into a procedure then just wrap the merge statement in `PROCEDURE find_duplicates IS BEGIN` and `END;` but, as Alex said, you can just run the merge statement directly. (You also don't need to use cursors)

Comment: Also, be careful running this multiple times. If you start with three rows with the id `111` then you will get out `111_V1`, `111_V2` and `111_V3` - which is as expected. If you then add in two more rows with id `111` (so, now, 5 rows total) and run it again you will get the previous rows `111_V1`, `111_V2` and `111_V3` and the new rows will be changed to `111_V1` and `111_V2` duplicating the previous version numbers. You would possibly be better to add a new `version` column and update that rather than updating the `unique_id` column - then the unique value would be the composite key.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to keep getting an error relating to the invalid table name and it seems to be to do with the merge keyword?

Comment: @MTO - a comment on the question suggests that won't be an issue, but totally agree.

Comment: @E_McAndrew - what is the full error you get? (Are you trying to use merge as part of a cursor, perhaps?)

Comment: I am just getting invalid table name. What do you mean by part of a cursor?

Comment: @E_McAndrew - just trying to guess what you are doing differently. I've used the same table name you did; I removed the `dbo.` as I don't have that schema, but I've already said to re-add that. If you're running my merge, with the `dbo.` reinstated, as the same user as your original code then I'm not sure how you can be getting that error.

Comment: Even running the straight SQL I am getting the error. 13:17:36  ORA-00903: invalid table name I have tried using just dbo.test as my table name and the same thing

Comment: Where did 'test' come from? The question has `dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File`, so you should be using that? Are you running the SQL as the same user that created the procedure (or the package it was part of), or as someone else?

Answer (score 2):

As Alex Poole Mentioned ,it is updating all the three row ,because the where condition doesn't differentiated between the rows,hence you can use rowid to find the duplicates and update the same.

```
PROCEDURE find_duplicates 
  IS

      cursor c_duplicates is
        select UNIQUE_ID,rnk,rdfrom (
          select UNIQUE_ID
                ,rowid rd
                ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY UNIQUE_ID ORDER BY rowid asc) rnk
                ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY UNIQUE_ID) cnt              from dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File
           ) where cnt>1;
     c_duplicates_rec c_duplicates%ROWTYPE;    
    BEGIN
        open c_duplicates;
          LOOP
            FETCH c_duplicates into c_duplicates_rec;
             EXIT WHEN c_duplicates%NOTFOUND;

            UPDATE dbo.Temp_Weekly_Export_File
            SET UNIQUE_ID=c_duplicates_rec.UNIQUE_ID||'_V'||c_duplicates_rec.rnk
            where rowid=c_duplicates_rec.rd;
          END LOOP;
          CLOSE c_duplicates;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    IF c_duplicates%ISOPEN THEN CLOSE c_duplicates; END IF;
     RAISE;
  END;
```

PS : I have not tested the code

Comment: The above code will update the first record in the duplicates also to 111v1 ,you can now modify the code to skip the update as per your requirement